# zero product list views Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, enhanced-ecommerce, impressions

Hi I am pushing impressions to GTM according to [Enhanced Ecommerce (UA)](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/enhanced-ecommerce#product-impressions):

```
dataLayer.push({ ecommerce: null });  // Clear the previous ecommerce object.

dataLayer.push({
  'event': 'impressions',
  'ecommerce': {
    'currencyCode': currencyCode,                      
    'impressions':impressionObj
  }
})
```

It is also appearing in the console:

[image: Impression1 console]

Image 2:
[image]

**But when I see it in the GA console, is displaying zero:**

[image: GA dashboard zero Product list views]

It's been many days now but I am not getting why this is happening

**Update**:

Here is the complete steps details:

Impressions:
[image: Impressions]

productClick:
[image: productClick]

PDP View:
[image: PDP View]

Add to Cart:
[image: Add to Cart]

Checkout Step 1:
[image: Checkout Step 1]

Checkout Step 2:
[image: Checkout Step 2]

Checkout Step 3:
[image: Checkout Step 3]

Purchase:
[image: Purchase]

Answer (score 0):

An enhanced ecommerce action is needed to indicate attribution - list impression alone is not enough. On a subsequent interaction with that product, be sure to include the list in an actionField object (when it makes sense to do so in your purchase funnel). When you do this, also make sure that the id for the product is the same.

For example, on product click:

```
dataLayer.push({
  'event': 'productClick',
  'ecommerce': {
    'click': {
      'actionField': {'list': 'Dog Wet Food'},
      'products': [{
        'name': 'Royal Canin Yorkshire Terrier Adult Wet Dog Food',
        'id': '100110',
        ...
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

Note that if you send a different value for list on another enhanced ecommerce action involving this product, the attribution funnel may break. The list specified on the most recent action is the one that gets credit. So if you specified the list on a particular action, like product click, and you feel this is sufficient for attribution, then you don't need to specify the list on other actions like product add to cart.  If you do need to specify the list on multiple actions, then make sure the value is the same, or if the value should be different on an action then just make sure that's what you really want to happen.

Comment: Thanks for reply doctor-spaceman. I understand what you are trying to say, but I am not getting why the funnel is breaking on start, i.e., on product impressions step. If it breaks on further steps, I get it, but why on starting. At least the product views should show

Comment: I have added images of whole journey. For now, I want the product view impressions to not be zro.

Comment: I see, sorry about that.  Focusing at the top of the funnel, then...  In GTM you should have one custom HTML tag for the data layer push, and a Universal Analytics tag to ferry that info to GA. On the Universal Analytics tag, I would double check that the GTM tag for product list impression set to "use data layer", there should be a checkbox for that in the tag settings.